# How do you use an if condition in a dropdownlist in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have the following ASP.net code that I want to port to C#.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text = "1" Then
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
    ElseIf DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text = "2" Then
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
    End If
End Sub
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: That's not `C#`. Please use proper tags..

Comment: @SonerGönül *"I have the following ASP.net code that I want to port to C#."* Please read questions properly.

Comment: @nmclean Have you ever look at the revision history? I wrote it in before the first edit. _I have the following ASP.net code that I want to port to C#_ doesn't even make sense. ASP.NET is not a programming language. _Even_ it was, this is not a suitable question for here. Stack Overflow is not a _code converter_ at all. This site is for specific programming problems. If someone try to code conversation, you can use some online tools or third party libraries. As a better way, learn both language and doing it yourself.

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes, have you? The original version, before you edited the tags, also said he wanted to convert it to C#. Also, nobody said ASP.NET is a programming language. (If the sentence read "I have the following event handling code", would you complain that "event handling" is not a programming language?) I agree that code translation requests are low quality questions, but I don't think "just do it yourself" is an appropriate response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code translated to c# is

```
protected void Button1_Click (Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "1")
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "2")
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Note there is no 'Handles' statement in c# to attach the event to the handler to use the below code in your Initialisation stages.

```
Button1.Click += Button1_Click;
```

Comment: please note there is a flaw here, you may want to do something different on each of the cases in your sample code the same action is being executed, I have maintained that in the translation

Answer (score 0):

When use http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ conversion link

[the result is:](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/?batchId=91f771b6-7a67-4c66-a7e0-b586776492ea)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "1") {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    } else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "2") {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here goes your C# equivalent code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "1") {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    } else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "2") {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Sometimes you better use some online converter which are readily available with zero cost.

1. http://converter.telerik.com/
2. http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/